# Can't access cups from ssh tunnel -Bad Request-

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cups

I have CUPS installed on different servers and I can connect to those using an SSH tunnel without any issue, but this server returns "Bad request" always.

All my servers have ***Ubuntu 16.04 Server***, including this one, and CUPS 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5, also I have the same configuration on all of them, but when I try to connect from my machine (connected to the cups server via an SSH tunnel) I get Bad Request and the log registers this:

```
E [17/Aug/2018:09:28:44 -0700] [Client 7] Request from "localhost" using invalid Host: field "192.168.0.104:6631".
```

P.S.: I post this after hours of googling and adding `ServerAlias *`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culpit!.

I was connecting using the SSH ProxyCommand (with netcat) to jump to an internal server of the remote network.

Now if I just do an `ssh -L...` I can connect without problems.